# how can i play my music application when the screen is locked?

Tags: android, android-intent

i make an android application that play a music i used the

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    my.release();
}
```

the problem is, when i close my screen the music is stopped

Comment: Use Service an Bind Activty to it. See : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 0):

You need an Android Service to play music in the background.
Have a look at official documentation :[Android Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

For your case, you can get plenty of sample codes. Try this:
[Music player on android](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-song-playback--mobile-22778)

Gud luck.!

Comment: i use Android Services as you have said and it works when i run the application (play) it starts and when i press (pause) it stops but when i get out the application it continue play  (this is what i want) but the problem is when i enter the application to stop it it doesn't stop

Comment: The issue must be in binding activity to your service..! Bind the activity in onResume() and unbind it in onPause() method.